# Restarting Game (reset scrolled screen)

Tags: python, scroll, pygame

I am having a problem with my game where when i try to restart the game from a game over screen it places the robot(player) back at its start position but the scrolled screen is still in the same position

Is there a simple way to reset the position of the screen or do you need to redraw all the original platforms.

Here is the main part of the code that is being used. I have not included the code to do with restarting the game but it simply runs game_loop()

Thanks for any help

```
import pygame as pg
import time
import random


pg.init()#initiates pygame

display_height = 690#Creates width and height of screen
display_width = 1024

#Colours
white = (255,255,255) 
black = (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,255,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
grass = (24,85,36)
yellow = (255,255,0)
lightGrey = (184,184,184)
grey = (73,71,65)

Robot_height = 99#Height of robot
Robot_width = 112#Width of robot
Bullet_Fired = False
PowerUp_Active = False
Robot_acc = 0.3 #Robot Acceleration
vec = pg.math.Vector2

gameDisplay = pg.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height)) #Sets display properties of window
pg.display.set_caption ("Game") #Title on window
clock = pg.time.Clock()

#Class for platforms
class Platform(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x,y,w,h):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.Surface((w,h))#sets width and height of platform
        self.image.fill(grass)#Fills rectangle with blue
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()#Rectangle set
        self.rect.x = x#x position
        self.rect.y = y#y position

#List of platforms x , y , width , height
PLATFORM_LIST = [[0,display_height - 40,2000,40],
                 [2300,display_height - 40,1000,40],
                 ]
#Platform group
platforms = pg.sprite.Group()

#Checks through "PLATFORM_LIST" and adds all the platforms the the grounp "platforms"
for plat in PLATFORM_LIST:
    p = Platform(*plat)
    platforms.add(p)

#Draws platforms to the screen
def draw():
    for plat in platforms:
        pg.draw.rect(gameDisplay, grass, plat)

#Class for robot
class RobotClass(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.Surface((Robot_width,Robot_height))#Height and width of the robot
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()#Gets rectangle of robot
        self.rect.center = (display_width / 2, display_height / 2)#Location of center of robot
        self.RobotPos = vec(display_width / 2, display_height / 2)#Position of robot as vector
        self.bottom = (0,0)#Bottom of robot
        self.vel = vec(0, 0)#Robots velocity
        self.acc = vec(0, 0.3)#Robots Acceleration

startX = display_width/2
startY = display_height/2

#Creates Robot
Robot = RobotClass()

#Jump function
def jump():
    #Checks pixel below robot to see if there is a collision
    Robot.rect.x = Robot.rect.x +1
    hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(Robot , platforms, False)
    Robot.rect.x = Robot.rect.x -1
    if hits:
        #Gives robot velocity of 5 upwards
        Robot.vel.y = -10

def game_loop():
    global PLATFORM_LIST
    global startX
    global startY
    global backgroundImg
    Robot.RobotPos = (startX,startY)
    score = 0 #Score
    lives = 3 #Robot Lives
    Robot_friction = -0.3 #Friction value
    vec = pg.math.Vector2 #Setting vec as vector quantity
    while True:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                pg.quit
                quit()
            #Starts acceleration when key is pressed
            if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_LEFT:
                    Robot.acc.x = -Robot_acc
                elif event.key == pg.K_RIGHT:
                    Robot.acc.x = Robot_acc
                elif event.key == pg.K_UP:
                    jump()
            #Adds friction to accleration to slow robot down when key is not being pressed
            if event.type == pg.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pg.K_LEFT or event.key == pg.K_RIGHT:
                    Robot.acc.x = Robot.acc.x * Robot_friction

        #Adjusts velocity of robot by adding the acceleration on each cycle
        Robot.vel = Robot.vel+ Robot.acc
        #gameDisplay.fill(sky)
        gameDisplay.blit(backgroundImg,(0,0))
        #Changes Robot position according to its velocity,acceleration and the friction
        Robot.RobotPos = Robot.RobotPos + Robot.vel + 0.5 * Robot.acc
        #Loads robot onto screen
        gameDisplay.blit(robotImg,(Robot.rect))
        #pg.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, Robot.rect, 2
        display_lives(lives)
        display_score(score)#lives

        #Sets bottom of robot to its position
        Robot.rect.midbottom =  Robot.RobotPos

        #Collision detection
        if Robot.vel.y > 0:
            hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(Robot , platforms, False)
            if hits:
                #Puts Robot on top of platform
                Robot.RobotPos.y = hits[0].rect.top + 1
                Robot.vel.y = 0        
        #Scrolling
        if Robot.rect.left < display_width/4:
            Robot.RobotPos.x = Robot.RobotPos.x + abs(Robot.vel.x)
            startX = startX + abs(Robot.vel.x)
            for plat in platforms:
                plat.rect.x = plat.rect.x + int(abs(Robot.vel.x))
        if Robot.rect.right > (display_width-display_width/4):
            Robot.RobotPos.x = Robot.RobotPos.x - abs(Robot.vel.x)
            startX = startX - abs(Robot.vel.x)
            for plat in platforms:
                plat.rect.x = plat.rect.x - int(abs(Robot.vel.x))

        draw()
        #Losing a life
        if Robot.rect.top > display_height:
            lives = lives - 1
            Robot.RobotPos.y = Robot.RobotPos.y - (40+Robot_height)
            Robot.RobotPos.x = Robot.RobotPos.x - 200
            Robot.vel.x = 0


        #Sets top velocity of robot    
        if Robot.vel.x > 6:
            Robot.vel.x = 6
        if Robot.vel.x < -6:
            Robot.vel.x = -6
        #Makes robot velocity = 0 when it is close to 0
        if Robot.vel.x < 0.05 and Robot.vel.x > -0.05:
            Robot.acc.x = 0
            Robot.vel.x = 0

        #Draws the platforms to the screen and adds them to platform group
        pg.display.update()#Updates display
        clock.tick(60)

game_intro()
pg.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: Why not just redraw it?

Comment: All the values of the platforms are all getting adjusted when the screen is being scrolled so in theory they are being redrawn just to the positions at which they were last at

Comment: is there a way to remove all sprites from the screen?

Comment: "I have not included the code to do with restarting the game but it simply runs game_loop()" That would've been the interesting part of the code. I hope you don't use recursion. It would also be really helpful for us, if you provided a [minimal, complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can just copy, paste and run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to reset all values in the main function (and globals) that were changed during the game to restart it. I've got a general example for you in which I just call a `initialize` function that creates a fresh sprite group and a player sprite (move the player rect with the d-key and reset the game with the r-key which calls `initialize` again).

```
import sys
import pygame as pg


class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos, *groups):
        super().__init__(groups)
        self.image = pg.Surface((40, 70))
        self.image.fill(pg.Color('royalblue'))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)
        self.vel = pg.math.Vector2(0, 0)
        self.pos = pg.math.Vector2(pos)

    def update(self):
        self.pos += self.vel
        self.rect.center = self.pos


def initialize():
    sprite_group = pg.sprite.Group()
    player = Player((100, 300), sprite_group)
    return sprite_group, player


def main():
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    sprite_group, player = initialize()

    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True
            if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_d:
                    player.vel.x = 5
                if event.key == pg.K_r:
                    sprite_group, player = initialize()
            if event.type == pg.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pg.K_d:
                    player.vel.x = 0

        sprite_group.update()
        screen.fill(pg.Color('gray12'))
        sprite_group.draw(screen)

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.init()
    main()
    pg.quit()
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: If you need more specific help with your game, you have to update your example, otherwise I can't be sure what's going on.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, helped me understand and implement it into my game. Thank you again